# Can't find the mistake of building up long equations

Tags: equations, split

I'm a freshman in latex and currently is stacked by the long equation.
I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to number the equations automatically rather than input the equation command every time?
2. I spent a lot of time in searching for the mistakes of my codes, any hints or advice will be appreciated.
3. How to write down a sentence after the equation and in the middle of space?
   For example, what should I do to type comments underneath each equation?

The codes are following:

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
   c_t  &=k_e^t+1\frac{1}{q}+k_s^(t+1)+(1-\tau_k^t)(r_ehk_e+r_sk_s)+(1-\tau_l)wl \\
     &\quad +(1-\lambda_e(h))k_e/q+(1-\lambda_s)k_s+T(\lambda)-A_s(k_s',k_s)-A_e(k_e'/q,k_e/q;\eta)
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Thank you so much for your attention!

Sincerely,
EK

Comment: Your (now very much simplified) code compiles with syntax-related error messages. What specifically are you trying to fix. Are you maybe contemplating changing `k_s^(t+1)` to either `k_s^{(t+1)}` or `k_s^{t+1}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple equations with no self-evident common alignment point, just use the `gather` environment and use `\\` to introduce line breaks.

How to find errors efficiently very much depends on types of errors that may occur. Syntax errors usually generate an error or a warning message. Errors of content may actually be easier to spot. E.g., in equation (6), I think `,\quad` is missing ahead of `0<\delta_s<1`. And, in the first line of equation (7), I think it should be `k_s^{(t+1)}` rather than `k_s^(t+1)`. Also in the first line of equation (7), the term `1\frac{1}{q}` looks really odd; however, I'm in no position to judge what may be correct. If `1\frac{1}{q}` is correct, then so should be `\frac{1}{q}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather' and 'split' environments

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\beta\theta\frac{1}{c_t}=\Lambda_t\\
\frac{\beta(1-\theta)}{l_t-1}=\Lambda_t\tau_l^t w_t(\lambda)\\
2\phi_s k_s^t+1-2(k_s^t)^2-k_s^t=0\\
2e^\eta\phi_tk_e^t+1-2\kappa_e k_e^t-k_e^tq=0\\
r_e^t=\frac{1}{q(1-\tau_k^t)} bh^\omega-1\\
k_e^t+1=(1-\delta_s)k_s^t+i_s^t,\quad  0<\delta_s<1\\
\begin{split}
c_t &= k_e^t+1\frac{1}{q}+k_s^{(t+1)}+(1-\tau_k^t)(r_ehk_e+r_sk_s)+(1-\tau_l)wl \\
    &\quad+ (1-\lambda_e(h))k_e/q+(1-\lambda_s)k_s+T(\lambda)\\
    &\quad- A_s(k_s',k_s)-A_e(k_e'/q,k_e/q;\eta)
\end{split}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What should I input" and s'=S(\lambda)" as a condition for the long equation?

Comment: @E.K - The answer probably depends on what kind of condition is in play. Writing `,\quad s'=S(\lambda)` at the end of the long equation (right before `\end{split}`) might work, as could writing `s'=S(\lambda)` right after `\end{gather}`. I'm not exactly confident, though, about this recommendation, in no small part because I don't see an `S(\lambda)` term in that equation. I do see the term `T(\lambda)`, but I have no idea how `S(\lambda)` and `T(\lambda)` might be related.

Comment: Which commands should I use if I want to number the equations in the next subsection?

Comment: @E.K - I'm afraid I don't understand your follow-up question. In particular, I don't see any connection between the existing equation(s) and subsection-level headers. Please clarify. If it is, de facto, a new query, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the align environment to span multiple equations and number each one of them, you can align them using the ampersand symbol as in a tabular enviroment.

The align environment can be used when you load the amsmath package, http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath.

A very simple example

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x&=y\
\intertext{therefore}
2x&=2y
\end{align}
\end{document}